# Set a variable in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, schema, search-path

I want to set search path in a function for which the schema name  to set the search path has to be selected from another table. I want to do something like :

```
set search_path to (select db_schema_name from Schenma_Name_Table  where lookup_id = 'xxxx')
```

this syntax is not working. It says - syntax error at or near "(".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set` can't use dynamic expressions, but you can use `set_config()` which accepts any expression:

```
select set_config('search_path', (select string_agg(db_schema_name, ',')
                                  from some_table 
                                  where lookup_id = 'xxxx'), false);
```

Note that I used `string_agg()` in case the query returns more than one value.